# jQuery.Load(.aspx) not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to load an aspx file into a div, but it won't work if the aspx file has asp.net controls.  (It's kinda the point.) If I only have html controls, it works fine, but not with runat="server".  I've stripped the main file and the .aspx file to almost nothing.  Also, the code behind isn't catching the data being passed in - PageSize.  Not even when only using the html elements.  Why won't the aspx page load?  I've tried taking out all the html tags, passed the data as "PageSize":"50", "PageSize":50 and other combinations.  No luck.

```
<%@ Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs"     Inherits="jQueryTutorial.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title></title>
<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#MyButton').click(function () {
            $('#OutputDiv').load('GetCustomers.aspx', { PageSize: 10 },
                function (response, status, xhr)
                {
                    if (status == "error")
                        alert(xhr.error);
                    //else
                    //    alert('Loaded');
                });
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="MyButton">Click to get HTML</button>
    <div id="OutputDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

.aspx file to be loaded:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GetCustomers.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQueryTutorial.GetCustomers" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Press me" />
<input id="abc" />
<%--    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Button" runat="server" />--%>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind asps file to be loaded:

```
using System;

namespace jQueryTutorial
{
public partial class GetCustomers : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var pageSize = 50;
        if (Request["PageSize"] != null) 
            pageSize = Int32.Parse(Request["PageSize"]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, what is the specific error you get?

Comment: Update:  I figured out part of the problem.  I was following an example from Pluralsight - jQuery Fundamentals.  That example was using an html page as the parent page.  I was using a default web forms application so the site.master file had a form tag.  I added "return false" to the click event so that returned all records, but I'm still not getting the data passed "{ PageSize : 50 }.  When I break in the form load event of GetCustomers.aspx, Request["PageSize"] is always null.

Comment: Another update:  Still can't pass the page size variable using .load, but .get works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated earlier, I'm following the Pluralsight jQuery Fundamentals tutorial.  I downloaded the source files and everything works from there.  It uses version 1.9.1.  I'm using 1.10.2.  I did get the $.load() to work by changing the syntax from

```
$('#OutputDiv').load('GetCustomers.aspx', {PageSize:10} );
```

to

```
$('#OutputDiv').load('GetCustomers.aspx', "PageSize=10" );
```

But this still doesn't work for $.post().

```
$.post('GetCustomers.aspx', "PageSize=15",
    function (data) {$('#OutputDiv').html(data);});
```

Also, I can't figure how to pass multiple data values.  I've now tried

```
"PageSize=10 var2=1"
"PageSize=10,var2=1"
"PageSize=10;var2=1"
"PageSize=10-var2=1"
```

How do I pass any data to post?
How do I pass multiple values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had an error message, but found it was due to a syntax error.  I fixed the error, but still can't read the PageSize data in the code behind using the $.Load() method.

```
$('#OutputDiv').load('GetCustomers.aspx', { PageSize: 10 });
```

However, I used $.get()

```
$.get('GetCustomers.aspx', { PageSize: 10 }, function (data) {
    $('#OutputDiv').html(data);
});
```

and this worked.  I would still like to know why using $.Load() won't pass teh PageSize data.

Thank you.